# Java compiler Error

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, javac, java

Hello I'm new to Java programming and well this is my following code...

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Hello, World!");

  }

}
```

but when I try to compile I get the following error...

```
test.java:1: class Main is public, should be declared in a file named Main.java

public class Main {

       ^

1 error
```

I acuqire the following code from this website 
http://www.learnjavaonline.org/

I'm using the Linux Ubuntu OpenJDK Development Kit (JDK)

I believe this is how you compile.

```
cristian@ubuntu:~/Java$ javac test.java
```

I'm new to Java so any tips or guides will be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name your file the same name as the class.  If the public class is `Main`, then your file must be named `Main.java`, not `test.java`.

Answer (score 1):

Either that or change the name of the class to test (notice the lower case -- class name must match file name).

Answer (score 0):

The name of your file and the name of your class must be the same. Either rename your file to "Main.class", or change your class to `public class test`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Hello, World!");

  }

}
```

Comment: No, it would not, it's case sensitive.